# Is it possible to create a page showing database content in real time, updating without reload page in Drupal 7?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, drupal-7

I have my custom module in Drupal and my custom page showing the content of a table of my own database. It is possible to refresh the content without reload page every X second? I need to know if it possible for I would want to save time trying to do something that is not possible.

Comment: Yes use ajax for this.

Comment: It's very possible and there are already plugins that do this. For example you can look into http://www.datatables.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use AJAX to reload the content of an element in the page every X seconds.

Since Drupal already includes jQuery you could do something like :

```
window.setInterval(function() {
  $('#myContentDiv').load('/url/to/my/database/content.php');
},timeInMilliseconds);
```

Comment: And what if... I created my page inside my module, defining it in hook_menu. I wrote the code building the page inside a function in my [module_name].pages.inc, not writing simple html, but, for example, selecting data from database using drupal function db_query... In that case, how i can refresh? My only option is writing an independent php page?

Comment: I don't know drupal that well, but it looks like there's actually an ajax framework integrated to it. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/group/ajax/7

Comment: Anyway i accept the answer for it is a perfect solution :)